# AngularJS How to pre-load global variable values from database

Tags: angularjs

I am storing the global variables in database and I want to initialize these global variables in AngularJS application on application load

Trying to implement this using AngularJS value service but got stuck when fetching the values from database on application load

```
angular.module("common.services").value("dashboardvalues",
{

    profiles:"",
    products:"",
    ...

})
```

On application load, the values of profiles and products should be fetched from database and these profiles and products can be used in any controller within the application. Can someone please help?

Comment: Sounds like a better job for an angular service

Answer (score 0):

These are many possible approachs:

1. **Delay booting of AngularJS**

   The advantage is that database data is available in the **config** phase of AngularJS. The disadvantages are that it complicates the code and users have to wait before seeing anything.
2. **Use a service**

   The advantage is that it is somewhat simpler. One possible disadvantage is there is a race between controller initialization and data arriving from the server.
3. **Use the `resolve` property of a router**

   The advantage is that it eliminates the race between controller and server.